# Can I prevent ImportCardinalityMismatchException getting swallowed?

Tags: mef

I have an application with lots of MEF, it's Import all the way down. In the debugger, with Break on Exception set, if a part is not found I can see an ImportCardinalityMismatchException being raised that tells me exactly what the missing import is. But then it gets swallowed, I assume by MEF, and eventually a log message pops out telling me about a different component that depends (possibly indirectly) on the failed one. Is it possible to get hold of that original failure outside of the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in .NET 4.5 you can use one of the [CompositionContainer constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136365%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overloads which accepts a [CompositionOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositionoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum. You need to pass it the `DisableSilentRejection` enum value.

Comment: Excellent! Unfortunately, we're still using .Net 4.0 :(

Answer (score 0):

One solution in .Net 4 is to use the `[Import(AllowDefault = true)]` attribute on the parameters to the importing constructor, then handle/log the failure yourself in the constructor body:

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public SomeView([Import(AllowDefault = true)] SomeViewModel context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
             LogManager.GetLogger("Composition").Error("No object found to satisfy import of 'SomeViewModel'");
             throw new ArgumetnNullException ("SomeViewModel");
        }
```